# Qgis 3 : QgsEditorWidgetSetup for date

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I need to make a date format in QGIS 3 but, in the program I need to use,
**QgsEditorWidgetSetup('Date',{'yyyymmdd'})**, I want to get this:

[image: here is what i want to have]

But I don't know how to use **QgsEditorWidgetSetup** to make the date looks like above image. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

This is my answer:

```
config = {'allow_null': True,
              'calendar_popup': True,
              'display_format': 'yyyyMMdd',
              'field_format': 'yyyyMMdd',
              'field_iso_format': False}
type = 'DateTime'
setup = QgsEditorWidgetSetup(type,config)
layer.setEditorWidgetSetup(6,setup)
```

I found it out because of following lines:

```
field = layer.fields()[6]
field.editorWidgetSetup().config()
field.editorWidgetSetup().type()
```

Qgis shows you all info to make it on code.